# UE4 Blueprint Cast failing without reason

Tags: casting, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am having a problem with casting in Unreal Blueprints. I am trying to cast from a widget blueprint to my game state to get the number of players remaining in a game to show on the HUD. I found out that the cast to MyGameState was failing, but I had casted to it the exact same way from multiple other blueprints with success, so I had no idea what the problem was. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this, and if so, I really appreciate it. Here is my blueprint:
[image]

Note: I know that this question has been asked before but I have not been able to find an answer that has worked for me. I would really appretiate not marking this question a duplicate unless an answer to another question actually works to solve my problem. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable for gameState object and set it in your event construct of your widget event graph , use the variable here in your shown code using if valid node .